# Configuring SSI in Tomcat 6.0

Tags: tomcat, server-side-includes

I'm trying to configure SSI with Apache Tomcat 6.0. Following this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssi-howto.html,
I have removed the comments aroud the ssiServlet in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`.
Also setup the previleged = "true" in context tag  found in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`

After setting this up, i tried to start the server ( i havent deployed any webapplications yet) and im getting this exception -

> Filter of class
>   org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIFilter is
>   privileged and cannot be loaded by
>   this web application

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a pretty late reply for this question, I am posting the solution that I found and worked for me. Hope this helps someone in future.

It is not a good idea to edit enable SSI in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` file as it will break all the applications in your `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` folder.

Best is to copy the `web.xml` file to `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/yourapp/WEB-INF/` folder and enable SSI directives there in.

Also set the `privileged=true` in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/yourapp/META-INF/context.xml` file.

I have detailed my steps and attached a copy of the files with correct values [here](http://webworksconsultant.com/backend/how-to-enable-ssi-in-apache-tomcat-6/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is

> previleged = "true"

in your question a typo? Because it should be `privileged="true"`. Tomcat won't complain about this, but the context won't be privileged and SSI won't be allowed.

Secondly, you say you've enabled the SSI **servlet**, but the error refers to the SSI **filter**. You should be using one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Yes.That is a typo.Im using the servlet not filter.Going to try out in the earlier Tomcat version.Thanks.